# How select random column value from Mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, random

I'm trying to fetch random column from database using `Rand()` function.
It's returning random value but many time it is returning duplicate.

This is what my database table look like.

| Column | Type | Null | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| no | int(30) | No |  |
| postid | varchar(100) | Yes | NULL |
| byuser | varchar(32) | Yes | NULL |
| likeslimit | int(30) | No |  |
| createdon | date | No |  |

And this is what my PHP code is.

```
$query = mysqli_query(
    $mysql,
    "SELECT postid FROM history ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1"
);

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo $row['postid'];
    }
}
```

I want it to always return random never the same till the end of data reached.

Comment: put the selection in array and check if `in_array` and ignore it

Comment: Can you please tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way `RAND` in mysql works and will repeat the results from time to time. But you can achieve such functionality by using mysql with php.

```
$query = mysqli_query($mysql, "SELECT postid FROM cacheTable WHERE 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$foundId = (int)$row['postid'];

if((int) $foundId === 0) { // NO records left in cacheTable then fill it up again
    mysqli_query($mysql, "INSERT INTO cacheTable (postid) SELECT postid FROM history");
    $query = mysqli_query($mysql, "SELECT postid FROM cacheTable WHERE 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $foundId = (int) $row['postid'];
}

mysqli_query($mysql, "DELETE FROM cacheTable WHERE postid=".$foundId); // DELETE the record

$query = mysqli_query($mysql, "SELECT * FROM history WHERE postid=".$foundId);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

`cacheTable` will have only one column - ID (primary key) which will hold the corresponding ID (primary key) from history. `cacheTable` structure:

```
|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|postid|varchar(100)|Yes|NULL
|-----
```

`cacheTable` will fill with all the ids from `history` table (it will be done once the `cacheTable` is empty). You will select `rand` result from the `cacheTable` and you will delete it then so it will not appear in the next selects. When we are out of records in cache table it will populate again.

**NB:** this approach has one major drawback - when you have new entries in `history` table they won't be available in cache table until it is empty and filled again.

Comment: What is the cacheTable Structure?

Comment: While my history table have column named `postid`

Comment: Now I have to play with primary keys

Comment: So `postId` will be the column in `cacheTable`.

Comment: Is it necessary to make it `primary key` ?

Comment: If you don't have Primary key in history then don`t do it if you don't need it. cacheTable will work with this postid column also

Comment: But at least add an index to this column in both tables so the select will be fast even if the tables becomes large

Comment: Thanks this is the answer to my question.

Comment: which variable is  my random id?

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in`

Comment: `$foundId` is you your random id

Comment: About the warning - did you replace `id` in my queries with your column name ?

Comment: Yep... I replaced all `id` with `postid`

Comment: can you please check my table structure?

Comment: Line 25  `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);`

Comment: my code start from **Line 24** and ends at **Line 38**

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\premium\curl\cron.php on line 25

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\premium\curl\cron.php on line 31

and `$foundId` returning **0**

Comment: Did you create `cacheTable` with the structure described in the answer?

Comment: ===Database vip

== Table structure for table cachetable

|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|postid|varchar(100)|Yes|NULL
== Dumping data for table cachetable

Comment: Tried returning **0**

Comment: First select will return no result until `INSERT` query takes place

Comment: Even the second query is returning 0

Comment: Then check the insert query - if you entering in the IF and execute the insert query manually

Comment: Gotcha! you wrote column name `id`  in insert query where it is `postid`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use loop and condition you want only 1 limit try this

```
$query = mysqli_query(
    $mysql,
    "SELECT postid FROM history ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1"
);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)

echo $row['postid'];
```

Comment: Still duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code [Samir Nabil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2715327/samir-nabil) Suggested :

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['dupes'] = array();

$query = mysqli_query(
    $mysql,
    "SELECT postid FROM history ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 1"
);

if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        if (!in_array($row['postid'], $_SESSION['dupes'])) {
            echo $row['postid'];
            $_SESSION['dupes'][] = $row['postid'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically array will be renewed everytime I refresh my page

Comment: maybe I gotta set value in `$_SESSION` ?

Comment: If you want the array to be persistent after page refresh you could store it in a session var ... code has been updated.